# Delete files recursively in multiple zip folders

Tags: powershell

I have a folder which contains many zip folders, inside the zipped folders there are many subfolders which contain files. I need to check every file within each zip file and if it is older than two years and delete it. I tried this and tested it using a hard coded path. However I may not know the name of each zip file in future and I need to be able to look through all of the zip folder.

```
# The two parameters. 
param([string]$limit, [string]$path) 

$stream = New-Object IO.FileStream($path, [IO.FileMode]::Open)
$mode   = [IO.Compression.ZipArchiveMode]::Update
$zip    = New-Object IO.Compression.ZipArchive($stream, $mode)

($zip.Entries | ? { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt $limit }) | % { $_.Delete() }

$zip.Dispose()
$stream.Close()
$stream.Dispose
```

Anyone any ideas on how I could approach this please?

Answer (score 0):

This script will find all the files that end with the extension zip" within the root folder. Pass in the root folder (where all the zips live) in as the $path variable.

```
param([string]$limit, [string]$path)

$zips = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -recurse *.zip

foreach ($zipfile in $zips) {
    $stream = New-Object IO.FileStream($zipfile.FullName, [IO.FileMode]::Open)
    $mode   = [IO.Compression.ZipArchiveMode]::Update
    $zip    = New-Object IO.Compression.ZipArchive($stream, $mode)

    ($zip.Entries | ? { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt $limit }) | % { $_.Delete() }

    $zip.Dispose()     # <- probably don't need this
    $stream.Close()
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I know its getting into each folder, my only problem is that it is deleting everything.

Comment: Am I misunderstanding the problem? I thought you had the zip modification part working and only needed to recursively find the zip files. I'm struggling to understand what you need done in the zip and what needs to be done in the filesystem.

Comment: Yes your code worked perfectly allowing me access to each file. However this line `!$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt $limit ` seems to be deleting everything rather than only files older than x number of days.

Comment: I can't test that. I don't know what assembly you're using for IO.Compression.ZipArchive. Can you update the question to include that? Or ask it as a separate question?